# What is more effective: filling variables with twig filters or passing them through the controller?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig, twig-filter

I've recently been using my own custom made twig filters. I've also been looking at ways to improve my performance.

I struggle in being able to distinguish when I should build a function in a Service, that then gets used by a Controller or if i should make it a twig filter instead. I am wondering which one executes faster or if there is any difference at all? To clarify my question I want to show how I fill the variable photos with both.

The twig template will look like this. It will just make image elements with the array of photos.

**/content/photos.html.twig**

```
    {% for photo in photos %}
    <img class="lozad card-img read-more-card-item-img" data-src="{{ photo }}">  
    {% endfor %}
```

Method 1: Pass the photos variable in a controller.
The controller would probably use a service called PhotoService and call the getReadMore function, while passing this to the twig template:

```
 function controllerAction(){
           $response = $this->render(
                '/content/photos.html.twig',
                 array(
                    'photos' => $photoService->getReadMorePhotos($posts),
                    'loadMoreUrl' => $url,
                    'limit' => $limit
                )
    }
```

Method 2: Use a custom twig filter instead:

```
public function getFilters()
 {
return array (new \Twig\TwigFilter('readMorePhotos', array($this, 'getReadMorePhotos')));
}

 //Twig filter
    public function getReadMorePhotos($posts)
    {
...
        $photos = [];
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
             $image = $this->getAbsoluteThumbsPath($post->getImage());
             if ($image != null && $image != "" && strpos($image, '/img/posts/default-post.png') === false) {
                  $gallery[] = $image;
             }
        }
...
        return $photos;
    }
```

In the twig template the photos variable will be filled like this:

```
{{set photos = posts|readMorePhotos}}
```

Is there any difference in both methods?

Comment: `filters` should be used to transform data, not fetching imho. Anyway this question is very opinion based and therefore offtopic on SO

Comment: @DarkBee, thanks. I guess this already answers my question. I need to set a clear distinction in what the twig filters in my project do and what the services do. i think your approach is the best. I should only use twig filters when I'm transforming the data

Answer (score 1):

very opinionated, so this answer essentially ... is an opinion.

the way I see it: the more non-standard functions/filters are used in a template, the worse off you're semantically. On one hand, whoever is editing or create the templates has to know of those functions/filter, which - in my opinion - is not desirable.

Also, as DarkBee already mentioned in the question's comment, filters are for transforming data, not fetching it. a twig function would be more appropriate, but I don't like it either because of the reason above (it also exposes *all* templates to that function, unless precautions are taken, on the other hand, it is expected to exist in all templates).

On the other hand, the template editor/creator also have to know about which variables may exist in the current context. So ultimately there is some prior knowledge required.

I want to propose a slightly different (and in my arrogant but humble opinion also *better*) option ...

As far as I see it, it would be better, if you could just use

```
 {% for photo in post.photos %}
       {# display of photos #}
 {% endfor %}
```

because they *are semantically* connected to the post, and also it makes sense to assume they are also structurally connected. Since your use case seems a little different, it would possibly be:

```
 {% for photo in posts.photos %}
```

which of course has different semantics and really screws with `posts` being an array, where `photos` be one element. However, imaginge the collection being an object, that has extra functions (I'll shamelessly extend doctrine's [`ArrayCollection`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/latest/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Collection.html)):

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Collection;

 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
 use App\Service\PhotoService;

 class PostCollection extends ArrayCollection {
     public $photoService;

     public function __construct(array $elements, PhotoService $photoService) {
         parent::__construct($elements);
         $this->photoService = $photoService;
     }

     public function getPhotos() {
         return $this->photoService->getReadMorePhotos($this->toArray())
     }
 }
```

and this is then to be called in your controller:

```
$response = $this->render(
    '/content/photos.html.twig',
    array(
        'posts' => new PostCollection($posts, $photoService),
        'loadMoreUrl' => $url,
        'limit' => $limit
    )
);
```

and can then be used as written above.

Why does this work? [`ArrayCollection`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/latest/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Collection.html) implements a few interfaces among which there is [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/ArrayAccess) as well as [`IteratorAggregate`](https://www.php.net/IteratorAggregate) (which extends [`Traversable`](https://www.php.net/traversable)), which lets you use it in a loop, and it will provide the collection it was given in its constructor (or which is changed in the modification methods), if the need arises, you can always retrieve an array via `ArrayCollection::toArray`.

Why do this? To get clean code.

Do I do this? No, tbh. But this is partly due to my habit of realizing almost all relations in the database, which in combination with ORM give me some of this for free.